# If $G'$ is a solvable derived subgroup of $G$ then is $G$ solvable?

Tags: group-theory, solvable-groups

My proof:

Assume $G$ is not solvable, and $G'$ is a derived subgroup of $G$

If $G$ not solvable then its derived subgroup never terminates at $1$.

But that would mean $G'$ is also not solvable.

This is a contradiction.

Hence if $G'$ is solvable then $G$ is solvable.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, the derived series must terminate somewhere.